# Unit Testing Graph SDK PageIterator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am creating a service that uses Microsofts Graph SDK which has a method for retrieving all applications from Active Directory. Originally I wrote the method with only a single page in mind and successfully mocked out the call in unit tests like below.

**Method**

```cs
public async Task<IList<Application>> GetAllApplicationsAsync()
{
    var applicationFirstPage = await _graphServiceClient.Applications
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

    return applicationFirstPage;
}
```

**Unit Test**

```cs
[Test]
public async Task GetAllApplicationsAsync_NoApplications_ReturnsEmptyAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var graphServiceClientMock = new Mock<IGraphServiceClient>();

    // Create an empty page of applications
    GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage page = new GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage { };

    graphServiceClientMock.Setup(m => m.Applications.Request().GetAsync()).ReturnsAsync(() => page);
    var graphClient = new GraphClient(graphServiceClientMock.Object);

    // Act
    var apps = await graphClient.GetAllApplicationsAsync();

    // Assert
    Assert.That(apps, Is.Empty);
}
```

I then proceeded to extend the method from the default query and loop through all pages to get a list of all applications. I used `PageIterator` as outlined in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp). When I went to update the unit tests I've struggled to adapt them to include `PageIterator`.

Calling `await pageIterator.IterateAsync();` throws a null ref exception, and I cannot think of how I'd mock or get around that.

**Extended Method**

```cs
public async Task<IList<Application>> GetAllApplicationsAsync()
{
    var applicationFirstPage = await _graphServiceClient.Applications
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

    List<Application> applications = new List<Application>();
    var pageIterator = PageIterator<Application>
        .CreatePageIterator(_graphServiceClient, applicationFirstPage, (a) =>
        {
            applications.Add(a);
            return true;
        });

    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

    return applications;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or advice on how to cover this method with unit tests. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pageIterator.IterateAsync()` internally access `page.AdditionalData` but `AdditionalData` are not initialized in the constructor of `GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage`.

You have to initialize `AdditionalData`.

```
GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage page = new GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage 
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
};
```

[PageIterator](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/a1352e36e119b95572d4dfa8cf0a411372cfa7ee/src/Microsoft.Graph/Tasks/PageIterator.cs#L73)

Comment: Where to use this code? When googling GraphServiceApplicationsCollectionPage, only this answer pops up

Comment: This helped me, thank you! In my case I was trying to IterateAsync() over an IAccessPackageCatalogAccessPackageCollectionPage that was pulled in with an $expand clause. i.e. graphClient.IdentityGovernance.EntitlementManagement.AccessPackageCatalogs.Request().Filter($"displayname eq '{catalog.DisplayName}'&$expand=accessPackages").GetAsync(); and then later create a PageIterator<AccessPackage> over the AccessPackages property of one of the Catalogs. This avoided the crash: graphCatalog.AccessPackages.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>().

Comment: Just in case someone else comes here having issues with the page iterator. do NOT include the OdataNextLink in your CollectionResponse otherwise this willl require you to add additional mocking for the page iterator GetNext page logic.